# How compile Eigen for MSVC++ 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, eigen

How compile Eigen for MSVC++ 2013? (Win8 Pro x32)
I downloaded  cmake and tried do this in cmd:

```
d:\lib\cmake-2.8.12.1-win32-x86\bin\cmake d:\lib\eigen-eigen-ffa86ffb5570\Eigen
```

[CMakeOutput.log on github](https://github.com/Nawy/cpp_example/blob/master/eigen_error_cmake)
How right to compile a Eigen? I don't know and don't know where I could learn about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigen is a header library. It doesn't need to be compiled, just included and placed in an include path.